# How to draw contious line in iphone screen

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I am just learning Core graphics.
So i have created a new project,include a UIView class.
Now i have following code in my UIView implementation file

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)sourceCoder
{
    if( ( self = [super initWithCoder:sourceCoder]))
    {
        //place any other initialization  here
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context,4);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, myColor.CGColor);


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context,startPoint.x , startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch* touchPoint = [touches anyObject]; 
    startPoint = [touchPoint locationInView:self];
    endPoint = [touchPoint locationInView:self];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    endPoint=[touch locationInView:self];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    endPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

But it is just creating the line and if again i try to draw then the previous line is lost.

But i want the previous line should not lost, How can i do this?

Comment: See "How to use drawRect to draw in a existing view?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724800/how-to-use-drawrect-to-draw-in-a-existing-view/6725315#6725315

Answer (score 0):

Set the view's [`clearsContextBeforeDrawing` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clearsContextBeforeDrawing) to `NO`.

Comment: No Success , it is still drawing the first line only. On subsequent drawing the previous drawing is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Set a UIImageView as background, save the context(lines) on there with:

```
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
<your imageView>.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```