# Canvas-like element

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, canvas, drawing

I'm looking for a "canvas-like" element to use in iOS apps. By "canvas-like" I mean that I want a surface on which I can draw basic shapes such as rectangles, lines, text, or images. I do not need 3D or other really advanced stuff -- rectangles and other images would be enough, text can be stored in images if required.

I can't imagine that no such API is available, but how do they call it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724800/how-to-use-drawrect-to-draw-in-a-existing-view/6725315#6725315

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With UIKit, everything that the user sees and interacts with is essentially a view. For instance, a button is a view, a table view is a view, etc. Your application should already have a main view controller, or a main window, which can contain zero or more views. You can draw on any view that you create, as long as you are in the position to implement the `drawRect:` method. Here's an example of implementing a `UIView` subclass on which can you can draw using CoreGraphics:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@end

@implementation MyView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    // here, you can draw shapes, for example, a circle:
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGContextMake(10, 10, 50, 50));
}

@end
```

Then, in order to add an instance of `MyView` to your application, either drag in a custom view in interface builder and change its class to `MyView`, or do this in `viewDidLoad` of your view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    MyView * aView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:aView];
#if __has_feautre(objc_arc) != 1
    [aView release];
#endif
}
```

You can learn more about what you can do in the `drawRect` method from the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Canvas like the HTML 5 `<canvas>`? Check "[Core Graphics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)" (a.k.a. Quartz 2D).